# Magento 2 Category page add custom view mode

Tags: magento2, category, custom, category-listing

On category page I want to add addition view mode as "expand" with "grid" and "list" mode.

[image]

If any one has created custom view mode for category page then help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to find solution to create custom view mode on category page. But no luck :(

So, I have check core files of magento 2. From where the view mode add, and I got idea how to create new mode. Below are the steps I have performed to create module.

> Step #1: Created a module registration file
>   app/code/Darsh/Expandmode/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Darsh_Expandmode', __DIR__
);
```

> Step #2: Created a composer.json file
>   app/code/Darsh/Expandmode/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "darsh/magento2-expandmode",
    "description": "Category page custom view mode",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "require": {
        "magento/module-backend": "~100.0.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Darsh/Expandmode"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

> Step #3: Created a module.xml file
>   app/code/Darsh/Expandmode/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Darsh_Expandmode" setup_version="1.0.0" >        
    </module>
</config>
```

> Step #4: Created a di.xml file to overwrite core magento
>   functionality. app/code/Darsh/Expandmode/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\ListMode" type="Darsh\Expandmode\Model\Config\Source\ListMode" />    
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList" type="Darsh\Expandmode\Helper\Product\ProductList" />    
</config>
```

> Step #5: Created a ListMode.php file to overwrite core magento
>   functionality.
>   app/code/Darsh/Expandmode/Model/Config/Source/ListMode.php

```
<?php
namespace Darsh\Expandmode\Model\Config\Source;

class ListMode extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\ListMode
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 'grid', 'label' => __('Grid Only')],
            ['value' => 'list', 'label' => __('List Only')],
            ['value' => 'grid-list', 'label' => __('Grid (default) / List')],
            ['value' => 'list-grid', 'label' => __('List (default) / Grid')],
            ['value' => 'list-grid-expand', 'label' => __('Expand (default) / List / Grid')]
        ];
    }

}
```

> Step #6: Created a ProductList.php file to overwrite core magento
>   functionality.
>   app/code/Darsh/Expandmode/Helper/Product/ProductList.php

```
<?php
namespace Darsh\Expandmode\Helper\Product;

class ProductList extends \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList
{
     /**
     * List mode configuration path
     */
    const XML_PATH_LIST_MODE = 'catalog/frontend/list_mode';

    const VIEW_MODE_LIST = 'list';
    const VIEW_MODE_GRID = 'grid';    

    const DEFAULT_SORT_DIRECTION = 'asc';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $coreRegistry;

    /**
     * Default limits per page
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_defaultAvailableLimit  = [10 => 10,20 => 20,50 => 50];

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry = null
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            \Magento\Framework\Registry::class
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns available mode for view
     *
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getAvailableViewMode()
    {
        $value = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_LIST_MODE,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
        switch ($value) {
            case 'grid':
                $availableMode = ['grid' => __('Grid')];
                break;

            case 'list':
                $availableMode = ['list' => __('List')];
                break;

            case 'grid-list':
                $availableMode = ['grid' => __('Grid'), 'list' =>  __('List')];
                break;

            case 'list-grid':
                $availableMode = ['list' => __('List'), 'grid' => __('Grid')];
                break;

            case 'list-grid-expand':
                $availableMode = ['expand' => __('Expand'), 'list' => __('List'), 'grid' => __('Grid')];
                break;
            default:
                $availableMode = null;
                break;
        }
        return $availableMode;
    }

    /**
     * Returns default view mode
     *
     * @param array $options
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDefaultViewMode($options = [])
    {
        if (empty($options)) {
            $options = $this->getAvailableViewMode();
        }
        return current(array_keys($options));
    }

    /**
     * Get default sort field
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getDefaultSortField()
    {
        $currentCategory = $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
        if ($currentCategory) {
            return $currentCategory->getDefaultSortBy();
        }

        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config::XML_PATH_LIST_DEFAULT_SORT_BY,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve available limits for specified view mode
     *
     * @param string $mode
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAvailableLimit($mode)
    {
        if (!in_array($mode, [self::VIEW_MODE_GRID, self::VIEW_MODE_LIST])) {
            return $this->_defaultAvailableLimit;
        }
        $perPageConfigKey = 'catalog/frontend/' . $mode . '_per_page_values';
        $perPageValues = (string)$this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $perPageConfigKey,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
        $perPageValues = explode(',', $perPageValues);
        $perPageValues = array_combine($perPageValues, $perPageValues);
        if ($this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            'catalog/frontend/list_allow_all',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        )) {
            return ($perPageValues + ['all' => __('All')]);
        } else {
            return $perPageValues;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve default per page values
     *
     * @param string $viewMode
     * @return string (comma separated)
     */
    public function getDefaultLimitPerPageValue($viewMode)
    {
        if ($viewMode == self::VIEW_MODE_LIST) {
            return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                'catalog/frontend/list_per_page',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );
        } elseif ($viewMode == self::VIEW_MODE_GRID) {
            return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                'catalog/frontend/grid_per_page',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

> Step #7: Applied changes in layout section
>   app/code/Darsh/Expandmode/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Darsh_Expandmode::product/list.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

> Step #8: Applied changes in layout section
>   app/code/Darsh/Expandmode/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?= $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } elseif ($block->getMode() == 'expand') {
        $viewMode = 'expand';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }else{
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $viewMode ?> products-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $viewMode ?>">
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <li class="item product product-item">
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $viewMode ?>">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                        <?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <?php
                            $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                        ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>

                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : '' ?>>
                                <div class="actions-primary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : '' ?>>
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>" action="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $postParams['action'] ?>" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
                                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                    class="action tocart primary">
                                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : '' ?>>
                                    <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                        <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($showDescription):?>
                                <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                       class="action more"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Learn More') ?></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "<?= /* @NoEscape */ $_product->getSku() ?>"
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As per my requirment I have made changes on above files, but basic idea you will get to create new custom view mode on category page.

Thanks :)

Comment: hi @Darsh, apart from the condition check $block->getMode() == 'expand', is anything else you modified in list.phtml?

Comment: what will be change in list page after selecting this option?