# Magento2 - How to change product view Grid or List without reload page?

Tags: magento2, product-list

I have search many hours to accomplish this but not get success to achieve last I tried [Stack overflow link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262834/magento-2-category-page-add-custom-view-mode)

and also add my custom jQuery in `list.phtml` file

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $(".mode-grid").click(function () {
                    alert('call Grid');
                    $('.mode-grid').addClass('active');
                    $('.mode-list').removeClass('active');

                }
            );
            $(".mode-list").click(function () {
                alert('call List');
                $('.mode-list').addClass('mode-list active');
                $('.mode-grid').removeClass('mode-grid active');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

but not get success, please help me to solve this ,I am new in `Magento` so also inform me where I make mistakes.

Thank you.

Comment: which error you are facing here?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying is fine and could work, you could also do it with an ajax request but is a more complicated approach.

For your approach, the css classes you might have to change will differ from theme to theme, for example in the one I'm working now its:

```
div.products.wrapper.grid.products-grid
```

that should change to:

```
div.products.wrapper.list.products-list
```

But also the markup on each kind of view is different, so you might have to play with that too as with a css class add/remove you are not affecting the other elements.

So in your js code, you are only changing the list/grid icons classes, you should also target .products.wrapper and toggle list/grid classes in it:

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $(".mode-grid").click(function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    alert('call Grid');
                    $('.mode-grid').addClass('active');
                    $('.mode-list').removeClass('active');
                    $('.products.wrapper').toggleClass('grid list').toggleClass('products-grid products-list');
                }
            );
            $(".mode-list").click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                alert('call List');
                $('.mode-list').addClass('mode-list active');
                $('.mode-grid').removeClass('mode-grid active');
                $('.products.wrapper').toggleClass('grid list').toggleClass('products-grid products-list');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it call jQuery functions but also reload page

Comment: You need to either remove the link from the markup or add stop propagation to js code, I've updated the answer

Comment: e.stopPropagation(); not work, instead of that use exit and return, in list.phtml @Thanks SantiBM

Comment: a pleasure to help, if you want you can edit the answer and mark it as valid!