# How can we add/register our own custom view mode in addition to default grid and list mode?

Tags: magento2, custom

I am new to magento and using 2.4.2. I have some prior experience in working with TYPO3 CMS. Ok. Now I want to add custom table mode to the defaults (Stores -> Catalog -> Storefront -> List Mode) which needs to list the category in the table view mode.

[image: Modes]

I can understand extending something in the core is not a easy job for a beginner. I have not found any great resources regarding this topic. So kindly share some advice on what needs to be done to fulfil my requirements and provide me some references on this topic in general.

Comment: What is your end goal i.e what do you mean by "which needs to list the category in the table view mode"? This setting changes output of vendor/magento/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml file either Grid or List. Perhaps you can more easily achieve what you need by overriding this file in your own theme?

Answer (score 0):

This surely is not a beginner task.

1. First, you need to add find out where that list render, then add one 1 as you wish.
2. Then you need to save your selected option in to the database -> you need to know what controller is it, what code that save your selection into the database
3. After all, you need to implement the appearance on the front. So you need to know block/template in Magento. You start to learn how the current/default/out of the box Magento works, then modify as you wish.

That whole thing can be found in Magento devdocs, it requires more than just reading but devdocs is a great place to start https://devdocs.magento.com/

Comment: I did it with the help of this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262834/magento-2-category-page-add-custom-view-mode) in two days with some modifications..